# What's wrong with my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can't seem to get the login page to work. I need to check the input email/password against the json data i get from the get request. something isn't working, but I can't figure it out.

```
function isSuccess() {
  var firstAdmin = {
    "name": "Admin",
    "email": "admin@example.com",
    "password": "secret",
    "admin": true
  };
  $.post("main.rb", firstAdmin);

  function isValidUser() {
    var json = $.get("/users", function(data) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(json);
      var x = document.form.usermail.value;
      var y = document.form.password.value;

      if (x === obj.users.user.email && y === obj.users.user.password && users.admin === true) {
        window.location = "userprofile/adminprofile.html";
      }
      if (x === users.email && y === users.password && users.admin === false) {
        window.location = "userprofile/userprofile.html";
      }
      alert("success");
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is `isValidUser()` called?

Comment: You have some issue with your open and closing braces or parens.

Comment: You might have an issue with security too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be in the following lines of code

```
if (x === obj.users.user.email && y === obj.users.user.password && users.admin === true) {
    window.location = "userprofile/adminprofile.html";
}
if (x === users.email && y === users.password && users.admin === false) {
    window.location = "userprofile/userprofile.html";
}
```

In both `if` conditions I think `users.admin` should be repalced with `obj.users.user.admin`

and in 2nd `if` condition `users.email` should be replaced with `obj.users.user.email` and same goes for the `users.password`

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
window.location
```

you'll get redirected to a new page and the

```
alert("sucess")
```

won't get called. Have you tried debugging the javascript step-by-step with firefox or chrome developer options?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code

```
  });
```

should just be

```
  }
```

I should point out that the function isValidUser() can only be called from within the function isSuccess() because it is a function inside another function.

Another thing to point out is that this appears to be client side JavaScript.  And you are providing an API for passwords to be read on the client side, in what appears to be plain text judging from the context.   You may want to consider the password authentication to be done on the server side.  So your AJAX sends the password and gets a simple yes/no response.  The password should not be available in some JSON by going to a url.  Obviously this is early days in your development as you don't even appear to have a way to distinguish the user, but I thought I should let you know anyway.